# Python-3.3 utf-8 id3 string decoding

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8

I have a problem to understand what is going wrong with this python code:

```
import chardet
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3

id3 = MP3("./test.mp3")

artist_name_byte = bytes(id3['TPE1'])
print( artist_name_byte)

encoding = chardet.detect(artist_name_byte)
print(encoding['encoding'])

artist_name_string = artist_name_byte.decode('utf-8')
print(artist_name_string)
```

the output is:

```
b'H\xc3\xa9l\xc3\xa8ne Grimaud'
utf-8
[Decode error - output not utf-8]
```

Why is there a decode error?

Comment: The code works for me (decodes to `'Hélène Grimaud'`), are you **certain** you don't have a *`UnicodeEncodeException`* (**encoding**) error?

Comment: You *most likely* have an exception **printing**, not decoding the artist name. What platform are you on? What is your console or terminal or IDE?

Comment: Can you show us the full traceback? The `[Decode error - output not utf-8]` line is your interpretation, which is not enough for us to see what actual exception you got.

Comment: @MartijnPieters you are right... I was launching the code from sublimetext. Running it from the windows command prompt all is ok! Thank you! If you write it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: configure the editor to set `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have a decoding error here:

```
>>> b'H\xc3\xa9l\xc3\xa8ne Grimaud'.decode('utf8')
'Hélène Grimaud'
```

Most likely you have an exception *printing* the unicode string instead. You didn't show the traceback, but you need to pay attention to the line that throws it and the exact name of the exception.

E.g. the `print()` line would be the last line in the traceback, not the `.decode()` line, and the exception would be `UnicodeEncodeError`, not `UnicodeDecodeError`.

Make sure your console, terminal or IDE is correctly set up and can handle Latin-1 codepoints. If Python tells you that `'ascii' codec can't encode character ...` then the console most likely is not telling Python what codec is acceptable, for example.

Comment: You can also open an output text file with utf-8 encoding and write the result to the file instead of using `print`. Any decent editor that supports UTF-8 will show you the text even in cases when console is not able to display it.